# C# - calling override method

Tags: c#

I am new to C# so please excuse gaps in my knowledge. In my code I have TWO types of foods Fresh and Regular. 
When determining cost Fresh items use different FindCost method than Regular.

I am having trouble working out how to call the FindCost() method for Fresh Items.

I think i need to use the base keyword somehow s:

```
namespace Groceries
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            PurchasedItem CheckoutItem4 = new FreshItem();
            CheckoutItem4.Name = "Rump Steak";
            CheckoutItem4.Condition = "Fresh";
            CheckoutItem4.Price = 11.99;
            CheckoutItem4.Weight = .8;


            ArrayList invoiceArray = new ArrayList();
            invoiceArray.Add(CheckoutItem1);


            foreach (PurchasedItem checkoutItem in invoiceArray)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"Quantity: {checkoutItem.Quantity} Weight: {checkoutItem.Weight}kg ");


            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class GroceryItem
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }


        public GroceryItem()
        {
        }

        public GroceryItem(string name, double price)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Price = price;
        }

        public static void Invoice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    public class PurchasedItem : GroceryItem 
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; internal set; }

        public virtual double FindCost()
        {

            double cost = Quantity * Price * 1.1; //1.1 is GST
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public class FreshItem : PurchasedItem
    {
        public new double Weight { get; set; } //kg

        public override double FindCost()
        {

            double cost = Weight * Price;
            return cost;
        }
    }

}
```

any help appreciated

Comment: You might want to reduce that down to just the code in question.

Comment: Try to avoid `ArrayList` - use `List<GroceryItem>` instead.

Comment: That white space hurts me

Comment: You code works fine. It's calling the correct `FindCost` method. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: base is for referencing the original, not overridden definitions of the method, why would you need that?

Unless there is more to calculation then shown above

I am not sure what are you asking, or where is the problem. To call the FindCost on fresh item, simply make an instance of fresh item and call the method on it?

Comment: This is working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is correctly calling the right `FindCost()` method, but you've defined your classes in a poor way, and hiding with the `new` keyword can make it call the wrong method.

You should make `GroceryItem` `abstract` and have both of your classes directly inherit from this. Then `GroceryItem` can has an `abstract` `FindCost()` method. Also, if you're hiding a method with `new` then you're probably doing something wrong. You should find that this eliminates all uncertainty when calling `FindCost()`.

Also, you should use `decimal` rather than `double` for financial calculations as `double` doesn't always accurately represent monetary values.

Here are the improved classes:

```
void Main()
{
    List<GroceryItem> invoiceArray = new List<GroceryItem>()
    {
        new FreshItem() { Name = "Rump Steak", Price = 11.99m, Weight = 0.8 },
        new PurchasedItem() { Name = "Cream", Price = 2.2m, Quantity = 1, Weight = 0.6 },
    };

    foreach (GroceryItem checkoutItem in invoiceArray)
    {
        if (checkoutItem is PurchasedItem purchasedItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Condition: {checkoutItem.Condition}; Quantity: {purchasedItem.Quantity}; Weight: {checkoutItem.Weight}kg");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Condition: {checkoutItem.Condition}; Weight: {checkoutItem.Weight}kg");
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public abstract class GroceryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract string Condition { get; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public GroceryItem() { }

    public GroceryItem(string name, decimal price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public abstract decimal FindCost();
}

public class PurchasedItem : GroceryItem
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public override string Condition { get { return "Regular"; } }

    public override decimal FindCost()
    {
        decimal cost = Quantity * Price * 1.1m; //1.1m is GST
        return cost;
    }
}

public class FreshItem : GroceryItem
{
    public override string Condition { get { return "Fresh"; } }

    public override decimal FindCost()
    {
        decimal cost = (decimal)Weight * Price;
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much I will go through each post. I posted all the code because I was worried i would omit something relevant.

Comment: I tried using your code however it get a ton of errors. I will go through some tutorials and learn more about inheritance =/ thank you though just tricky without knowing all the fundamentals.

[image of errors ](https://image.ibb.co/hF7MKF/errors.jpg)

Comment: @bronxsystem - You should be able to work from my code to get your code working. Because of the changes I made - which you should use - it made your existing code fail, but debugging those issues is a skill you should learn. To help I've updated the code in my answer to include how you can use it. Let me know if you're not using C# 7 as the `if (checkoutItem is PurchasedItem purchasedItem)` won't work on earlier versions of C#.

Comment: thank you I will try again (: I am using C#7 will try again

Comment: thank you it works perfectly. Issue is I just don't completely understand it. I appreciate the help I was totally stuck. Now I know how to get it to work I just have to understand it.


I have been trying to learn C# for two months keep running into brick walls. thanks thanks thanks

Comment: @bronxsystem - No trouble. It's easier to understand working code so I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you set Weight with the reference of type PurchasedItem : 
CheckoutItem4.Weight = .8;
You set the field Weight declared in class PurchasedItem, but the method FindCost use the field Weight defined in class FreshItem that is not initialised.  So, just remove de line : *public new double Weight { get; set; } //kg*.  You do not need to redefine this field.

Comment: It works when I use your way however the assignment asks me to use the Weight member in the fresh class. Weight was only meant to be in the FreshItem class.

I will go through it all again with the advice posted in thread thanks all

Comment: I have never seen this used before
'code'
 public override string Condition { get { return "Regular"; } }

I want to learn more about it is there a specific term for that? I will need to review inheritance, abstraction and overriding etc but is there a name for that line of code?